# Finding overlapping kmers in a python string

Tags: string, combinatorics, biopython

I'm trying to find the counts of binary 5-mers in a long binary string. 
That is,
Given a String of say: seq='000111100101101'   , I want to count how many times each 5-mer appears. 
I generated a list of all 32 iterations easily enough :

```
import re
from itertools import product  
combo = [ ''.join(x) for x in product('01', repeat=5) ]
```

My problem now is counting the occurences of each combination in overlaps. 
(That is, I want to check in overlapping windows of length 5:  0:4, 1:5, 2:6, 3:7... (Total of Sequence Length-4 windows). I'm unsure how to do so in a way that counts the overlapping windows. (combo[i] = seq.count(i) Doesn't seem to work).

Thanks!

Example Desired ouput for a given seq:

```
seq: '11111101'
Combos: (11111 :2 ,  11101 :1 , 11110 :1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple python implementation with `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def C(s):
  d = defaultdict(int)
  for i in xrange(len(s)-4):
    d[s[i:i+5]] += 1
  return d

 C('010100101010101001111010000000001')
```

Comment: What does 'code' d[s[i:i+5]] do exactly?  (I want to understand why it can catch in overlaps.  will d hold the various iterations as keys? (Not just their counts/Value?) THANKS!

Comment: `s[i:i+5]` is substring of string `s` of length 5 from position `i`. `d` is a defaultdict object, which is same as dictionary with a default value (0) if key is not mapped. So, `d` counts number of occurrences of each different substring of length 5.